# Why I changed the size of the form in WinForm, but the size of the form is still a fixed value？

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The display in the design interface is normal, but it is short after running. This situation did not happen in my program before, I don’t know. why.
[image: Comparison of design interface and actual operation interface]

[image: Form property settings]

Comment: Try changing `AutoScaleMode` to `Font`, not `DPI`.

Comment: "changing AutoScaleMode to Font, not DPI" is useless, but the interface is shrunk into a ball @Andy

Comment: Start applying this: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103). Enhance with: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms)

Comment: Changing `AutoScaleMode` to `None`. ?

Comment: When I changed the 'Localizable' option from True to False, all this was resolved. It’s weird...

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the Localizable option from True to False, all this was resolved. It’s weird...
[changed the Localizable option from True to False](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gapyw.jpg)